# Ignoring Duplicates in Beautifulsoup Find_All

Tags: html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

So i'm trying to parse some HTML by only returning paragraphs and and list tags, which is easy enough. Below is an example of what i've done so far:

```
def main():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').find_all()
    print "output:"
    for tag in soup:
       if tag.name == 'p':
          print tag.text # Text to be used to create a RichText object
       elif tag.name == 'li':
          print tag.text # Text to be used to create a RichText object
```

HTML:

```
"<html><body><p><p>INSIDE TAG</p></p><ul><li>LIST1</li><li>LIST2</li></ul><p>OUTSIDE TAG</p></body></html> "
```

Output:

```
INSIDE TAG
INSIDE TAG
LIST1
LIST2
OUTSIDE TAG
```

As you can see, if a tag contains another tag of the same type, in this example a paragraph, it is repeated and i was wondering if there was a better approach to this to avoid this from happening? The main issue is that it may be any tag where this can happen, as i have no control over the input HTML. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for tag in soup:
    if tag.name == 'p' and tag.parent.name !='p':
        print tag.text # Text to be used to create a RichText object
    elif tag.name == 'li':
        print tag.text # Text to be used to create a RichText object
```

You can check tag's parent name to filter it